# Is it possible to resolve navigation outcome in order to validate it?

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I've got a WebFilter that redirects to the login page in my application. In order to redirect *back* to the referring page I've also added a view parameter called *redirectOnLogin* which is then used on successful logins in order to perform the final navigation.

If one were to manipulate this query parameter, one could easily provoke JSF navigation errors. I would therefore like to pre-empt this by checking that the outcome is valid but I've not been able to uncover a mechanism for **pre-validating a JSF outcome**.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and best is to make sure the redirectToLogin parameter cannot be manipulated. Or that manipulation is detected.

You could solve this in (at least) two ways

1. Taking the original page name, adding a 'salt' to it and creating a hash.
2. Addin this has that in the request to the login server
3. Make sure it is returned by the login server (maybe adding it as # to the return page or as a param.
4. On receiving it on the 'redirectOnLogin' page, use the page name, the same salt and create a hash in the same way. Compare these and if they match you are fine, if they don't throw an error.

Or you could

1. Store the 'redirectOnLogin' page in a session to
2. Check on returning from the login server if it matches with the page you end-up on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Both will work, surely. Indeed, I was thinking along these lines already but I would still like to know whether the mechanism in question exists or is possible to create.

Comment: I checked all the methods from the FacesContext a few levels deep and did not find any that would return a 'true' or 'false' to see if a view exists (that is with **my** knowledge). But what if it does or does not exist, how would you act on that result? If it does not exist, you'll get a 404 anyway. And if it does exist? Let it go trough (without wanting to know if it was manipulated)? So the only one who might know if it is possible at all is BalusC, but I'm not sure he'll provide an answer for this theoretical question. Cheers...

Comment: Well, if the outcome is invalid I would log information regarding said occurence and redirect "home" instead. If it is valid, I would just go there. After all, if the user doesn't have the credentials to go there he would just be redirected back to "home".

Thanks for your input! Yes, I'm still hoping to see BalusC pull a rabbit out his hat. Last time I asked such a question, he put the desired functionality into OmniFaces. :)

Comment: B=No idea if  he'll put this into there if there is a solution (I would think not) Since you can still log it when it is 'wrong' in the proposed solution. And a security solution should imo not be dependent on the mvc solution (I would not use a jsf view parameter but a generic filter or even an existing security framework